Не могу убрать фон картинки в CustomTkinter
У меня проблема, при добавление PNG картинки на экран, то фон ее картинки остается прежним цветом как и стандартный фон окна (черный). Вот сам код:
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

ctk.set_appearance_mode("system")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("CustomTkinter")
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        frame_image = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("icons/frame.jpg"), size=(600, 600))
        self.label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="", image=frame_image)
        self.label1.place(x=-370, y=0)
        
        shy_light_1 = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("icons/shy_light_1.png"), size=(100, 100))
        self.label2 = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="", image=shy_light_1, fg_color="transparent")
        self.label2.place(x=50, y=120)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

Вот сама проблема:

Есть ли какое-то решение? Или CustomTkinter не позволяет такой возможности?

В tkinter (и CustomTkinter) у label непрозрачный фон. Нужно создать canvas, на него добавить одну картинку, поверх нее другую. Не внутри label, а с помощью create_image (это в tkinter, в CustomTkinter что-то похожее должно быть), тогда по идее должна получиться вставка без фона.
